# maven quickstart in intellij idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

There is a section "maven in 5 minutes" on the apache maven website. The following script is written in it. If you execute this script in cmd, then the project is created well.

```
 mvn archetype:generate
-DgroupId=com.mycompany.app
-DartifactId=my-app 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart 
-DarchetypeVersion=1.4 
-DinteractiveMode=false
```

However, it can't be done in Intellij IDEA. When executing File->New->project->Maven->maven-archetype-quickstart, a project will be created without the src folder (->main,->test, etc.) and empty pom.xml . What is the problem?

Intellij IDEA 2020.3.4

Comment: Worked for me in IDEA 2021.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled windows. (I needed it anyway) and installed intellij IDEA 2021.3 instead of 2020.3. Everything worked. Some of this has affected. Perhaps reinstalling the same version would also solve this problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project using IntelliJ, it takes a while to set up the project. You should see a small pop-up on the lower right corner which says "1 process running". If you don't see it, try "Invalidate caches / Restart". This can be found under File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Attaching the screenshot for your reference.
[image]

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work for me.